# setImageResource() will not update my ImageView size/content directly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a row in a listview activity where an image should be changed when the row is selected. The new image is identical but larger (double size) than the original image. It is supposed to be reduced when it is deselected (Selection is implemented using my internal selection, not the android keyboard selection kind) again.

Problem is when (selected) I change the picture (at the time of bind) of my ImageView () using setImageResource() it does not update to the new larger version in my List row on the first click. Second execution of bind works fine. The same applies for the old item being deselected. The change to a smaller icon does not get in effect until a second click. The problem repeats itself each time I select another row than the currently selected and starts working correctly again on the second click.

I have stepped through code and seen that I pass the right id to the ImageView and this is prooved by the fact that another View showing a yellow border on the same row is changed to visible/hidden when selected/deselected.

To me it feels like the setImageResource() does not refresh the view immediately, but using invalidate() on the view or the row has no effect at all.

Is this a bug (how to work around) or do I do something wrong?

Code: (from my holder class using the holder pattern - executed by the adapter bind method)

```
@Override
public void refreshFromCursor(final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
...
boolean selected = adapter.getSelectedPosition()==cursor.getPosition();
if (selected){
  selectedIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Show a "selected" yellow border indicator to the left
} else {
  selectedIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide a "selected" yellow border indicator to the left
}
...
if (selected) completionResId = R.drawable.folder_selected;
else completionResId = R.drawable.folder;
...
statusIcon.setImageResource(completionResId); // !!!!! This is where I set the image that does not refresh/resize
...
}
```

Also tested exchanging the

```
statusIcon.setImageResource(completionResId);
```

with

```
statusIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(completionResId));
```

but nothing changes in the problematic behaviour

Comment: Looking at Android references i found that:

This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a **latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)** or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Maybe this can be your problem. Have you tried to use setImageDrawable???

Comment: @Bruno
No. I have not tried setDrawable yet. Need some rewriting of code to do that.  
  
I have read the text you refer to from the javadoc. But as I have understood this "hickup" should affect performance in terms of waiting time because GUI thread is occupied, but not functional regarding update of the image. Even if so where the case, how would I force the ImageView to update directly!  
  
I find it hard to believe that the setImageResource() method doesn't update ImageView after execution. That would make it worthless for dynamic usage.

Comment: I completely agree with you and i am not understanding the hickup too. In my opinion, setImageResource should works fine, or at least call invalidate should solve, but you tested. I did not test to use setImageDrawable,  it is just  a attempt. Maybe it can works fine.

Comment: @Bruno Tested by exchanging the code with statusIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(completionResId)); Exactly the same behaviour!
Updated original post.

Comment: :( Well, You could try use the invalidateDrawable method with setImageDrawable, but i did not test. Sorry for this, at right moment i don't have Android configured in my pc at my workplace.

Comment: Unfortunatlely I thought about that and tried it already. Changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is about the way you have implemented,

if you provide us the full code of refreshFromCursor(...) function we can have better understanding of what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack. just make your drawable bigger

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="500dp"
android:height="500dp"
android:viewportWidth="139"
android:viewportHeight="139">

<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="M117.037,61.441L36.333,14.846c..." />
</vector>
```

here I set the drawable to be drawn on a 500dp canvas (instead of a 139dp one that was there originally) and it did the trick. no more weird tiny icons that later increase in size.